# Excel gives weird R square calculations?

Tags: excel, statistics, prediction

This is really weird. I calculate R^2 values with Excel in two different ways and the results differ hugely. Why?

1) First I use Excel to do a  linear regression via a graph, and use the "Add Trendline..." right mouse button functionality to specify Intercept = 0. The R square value shows -3.253. The regressed equation is Y = -0.1321 * X

2) Then I use Excel to do a linear regression via LINEST function. I highlight 5x2 rows and in the top left cell, I type "=LINEST ([Y vector]; [X vector], FALSE, TRUE). The False means the intercept is 0, and the True means Excel should print additional regression statistical information. Then I press CTRL + SHIFT + Enter. This will show me additional statistics, such as R^2 value in the third left cell. Which turns out to be 0.11166. The regressed equation is Y = -0.1321 * X

My question is; what am I doing wrong in calculating R^2 with the graph? Python and statsmodels.api confirms that R^2 is 0.11166, and the regressed equation is Y = -0.1321 * X.

```
Y = 
0.0291970802919708
0.141801551718973
0.145668034655723
0.0691229530946433
0.0431577486597426
0.133618351873374

X = 
-0.35551988
-0.20577599
0.10780785
-0.25028796
-0.42762184
0.02442197
```

Comment: Is seems that this is an old bug. R^2 generated by the scatter plot is incorrect when the intercept is 0. Here is a KB article about this issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/829249/you-will-receive-an-incorrect-r-squared-value-in-the-chart-tool-in-excel-2003

Comment: It's a bug. I would also advice if you're in statistics with Excel, to load https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Analysis-ToolPak-to-perform-complex-data-analysis-6c67ccf0-f4a9-487c-8dec-bdb5a2cefab6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: This was helpful. I wanted to add two notes: 1) The link provided by @JiříPešík seems to be broken now; can anyone provide an updated link? I found a related (but not super helpful) discussion here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/r-squared-different-in-trendline-vs-linest/4f819d1a-1a37-4c08-b47b-4688103ff666 . 2) I found similar issues with the R^2 values of power functions generated through excel scatterplots compared to my lm(log(y) ~ log(x)) results in R. The R^2 values generated with excel's LINEST() function did match my R output, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. Scatter plot does not return correct R^2 when the intercept is 0. This is an formula fo R^2

[image: R^2 formula]

where

[image: SStot formula]

If you use standard regression model, you use average value of y as y̅. But when you assume that the intercept equals 0, you need to set y̅ as zero. If you use the average value of y instead of zero, you get the R^2 = -3.252767.

You can see the calculation here. The SStot wrong column uses average value of y as y̅. Then the R^2 value equals to -3.252767. If you use 0 (as I did in SStot right column), then you get 0.111.

[image]

It is an old bug described by Microsoft here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/829249/you-will-receive-an-incorrect-r-squared-value-in-the-chart-tool-in-excel-2003
You need to use the LINEST function to get correct R^2 value.

Answer (score 0):

Me and my fellow engineers just got tangled up in this. Based on this discussion and what we observed, the R^2 is wrong all of the time except when Excel calculates the best y-intercept. Any other y-intercept (either forced through Zero OR user-defined), is wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).